How to draw a circle using text characters on the Linux terminal using NASM?
I'm a university student and I don't get how to draw a circle or a rectangle. I'm printing text in a terminal window, not using lines, so it will technically look like a circle made with * characters.
I can't use python or have the shape made beforehand. I need to use NASM to compute where the stars go for a circle, and draw them.
This is an example to print one * on the terminal:
;print a star (asterisk)
section .data
star db '*', 0xA, 0

section .bss
;uninitialized variable

section .text
global _start
_start:
mov eax, 4    ; system call for print
mov ebx, 1    ; standard output
mov ecx, star ; memory location
mov edx, 2    ; length
int 0x80

mov eax, 1    ; system call for exit
mov ebx, 0    ; exit
int 0x80

How do I print out the star to the shape of a whole circle?

related: How to print an equilateral triangle based off user input in NASM? which shows how to draw a diamond: print spaces and newlines, and horizontal lines of '*' by looping or filling a buffer. For every position you loop over, decide whether it's inside or outside the circle and print a '*' or ' '. A rectangle is the easiest shape; start with that. Three loops should do the trick, for the top row, the sides, and the bottom row.

Are there any requirements to the radius of the circle? Just print * and claim it was a circle of radius ε. Or print ◯ (U+25EF large circle) if you like it a bit larger.   @Peter Considering that Zeti is a college student, I think the mathematical definition of circle applies, i. e. the set of points in a plane that have the same distance r to a point C.

Do you need to draw a circle or is any ellipse fine? I realized that the character cells are typically taller than wide so if you just print * that are certain number of character cells (“blocks”) away from the center, you will see an ellipse (not necessarily a circle, although possible).

You might want to study https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm. Draw your circle in a memory buffer the same size as the text screen (80x25). A set point means you write the code for an asterisk. When done you display it all at once using a length in EDX of 1999. Don't use 2000 or else the screen will scroll!

Since you evidently already know how to produce output, can use .data and distinguish between memory and value operands, this question seems to be about the process.

Achieve the task in a high‑level programming language of your choice.
Since you mentioned it I guess you are proficient in Python;
Python seems suitable.
This step is solely about ensuring the algorithm you devised can achieve the task.
Directly editing and modifying your algorithm in assembly is possible, but takes longer (and may be frustrating to the beginner).
Once you are done, create a revision (git commit or whichever source code revision system you like), but this optional.

Translate potentially difficult parts of your algorithm using inline assembly.
If you have chosen a programming language that allows comfortable inline use of assembly, use this feature as an intermediate step.
By comfortable use I mean, for example, you can use already declared high‑level programming language identifiers, or the compiler complains about data size mismatches (e. g. load 64‑bit variable into 32‑bit register ↯) unless overridden.
You may notice that some high‑level language constructs do not translate as straightforward into assembly as you desire.
With this knowledge you can go back to step one and simplify the algorithm.
Ensure that everything still works correctly after the simplification before paying attention to the assembly implementation again.
As soon as you are satisfied with your program, create a new source code revision.
You may have accidentally introduced some (new) programming mistakes (“bugs”), so it may come in handy to refer to a functional version.

Finally, translate the entire program to assembly.
Start with your boilerplate program and add code little by little.
For example, first print an asterisk at a specific constant position on the screen before generalizing your code toward printing asterisks at variable positions.
This allows you to distinguish between what works vs. what does not work once/if you experience bugs.


Notes:

Peter already mentioned the method of editing a buffer.
Another yet more complicated method is to emit recognized console_codes(4) to position the writing cursor.
This works well if you only want to display shapes, it does not work well if output is redirected to a regular file (unless you cat that file to a Linux terminal of sufficient dimensions again).
The advantage is really only that you do not have to deal with the restriction of printing/“drawing” the shape line by line (from top to bottom).

As I mentioned, character cells are typically taller than wide.
Furthermore, picture elements (“pixels”) are not necessarily square in shape (especially cathode‑ray tube television screens featured tall bars), nor is the horizontal pixel density necessarily equal to the vertical pixel density.
While it is technically possible to examine the currently loaded font (for glyph dimensions in pixels, setfont ‑o /dev/stdout), EDID information (for screen dimensions in meters), and the number of columns and rows on the screen (to infer the screen dimensions in pixels [assuming full screen utilization]), there is to my knowledge no convenient interface; for educational purposes the bulk of your source code should focus on the shape drawing task.
I think the best you can do is to insert a “calibration step”, i. e. prompt the user “How long is this horizontal bar of asterisks in millimeters?”, “… this vertical bar …?” before showing a circle (or the closest possible approximation thereof).

In a production program you would use something like the libcaca – one of probably many ASCII art libraries – routine caca_draw_circle.
There is no point in re‐inventing the wheel.



An alternative to filling in a 2d buffer is to create an array of {X,Y} points, then optionally sort by Y. Each line on the screen represents a range of Y values, using a scaled factor for screen aspect ratio and line size. Then for each line print all of the scaled X values for that range of Y values, then continue to the next line. This is how old programs printed graphs on line printers.
https://rcgldr.net/code/lpgrph1.jpg
https://rcgldr.net/code/lpgrph2.jpg
https://rcgldr.net/code/lpgrph3.jpg
